# Heroku Server 500 error on particular page

Tags: django, heroku

Just deployed a Django app on Heroku. Everything works except for one page of my site which creates a Server 500 error (even though it works fine on my local development server).

The page raising the error doesn't do anything unusual.  It makes some database calls, renders some forms, implements JQuery, etc.  Any clue what this could be or how I can debug it?

Also, I thought this might be a data issue since my data in Dev doesn't match my data in production, but I checked and this doesn't seem to be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because I didn't include a `runtime.txt` telling Heroku to use Python 3 instead of 2 which subsequently raised an error in one of my views where I called super() with no args.

Answer (score 1):

enable `DEBUG=TRUE` in your django `settings.py` file or type in console `heroku logs --app your_app` to get heroku server logs.